# Is it possible to call the sqlite3_vfs_register() function from an Android app?

Tags: java, android, c++, sqlite, android-ndk

The SQLite library offers the [sqlite3_vfs_register()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/vfs_find.html) API function to allow applications to register a set of callback functions used to access the file system (i.e. xOpen(), xRead(), xWrite() etc.).

And Android features [java interfaces](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) that allow applications to use SQLite to read and write databases.

Is it possible, by hook or by crook, to call sqlite3_vfs_register() from Android application code compiled using the NDK? So as to affect the future operation of the database connections used by java interfaces like SqliteDatabase?

sqlite3_vfs_register() works by modifying global variables within the library (i.e. variables declared with file scope within the sqlite source code). So compiling the SQLite code into the application using the NDK will not help. If I did that then calling sqlite3_vfs_register() would wind up modifying the "wrong" set of global variables.

Comment: i don't think so ... but what about SQLCipher for Android ... it provides the same java interface ... i think you could modify the source to register anything you want

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I think they basically copied a lot of code out of the Android core to do that. It looks like it was no small effort to get it to build externally - lots of dependency issues to resolve. I'm starting to think that that might be the only plausible approach though.